# Is NumberFormat.getInstance guaranteed to create a new instance?

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(spotDecimalPlaces);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(spotDecimalPlaces);
```

Is it "safe"? Is `NumberFormat.getInstance()` guaranteed to return a new `NumberFormat` object each time?

Or is there a possibility that `getInstance()` returns the same instance? (in which case this code would affect everywhere else in the JVM that happens to use `getInstance`...)

Looking at the source code it *seems* like it returns a new instance each time. The JavaDoc is frustratingly vague on the matter.

If the above code really is "safe", then it seems to me that `getInstance()` is a poor name for this method - that it should have been called `createInstance()`.

Is `NumberFormat.getInstance()` guaranteed to always return a new instance?

Comment: If it's vague then I wouldn't rely on it at all

Comment: Yes arguably the most robust thing to do is to create a new DecimalFormat. I don't really want the current "locale" to affect the behaviour in any case...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. The code either get an instance from a `NumberFormatProvider` (which must, according to the documentation, return a new instance), or it creates a new instance of `DecimalFormat`.

Logically, since `NumberFormat` is mutable, returning the same instance or cached instances would make the method completely unusable.

Comment: How do you get a NumberFormatProvider ?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 You don't. But NumberFormat.getInstance does, internally.

Comment: the Instance you get is not safe with respect to parse

Comment: @Edmondo1984 It's not thread-safe, but that is not the question here. The question is: is it safe to assume that getInstance() returns a new instance, and thus to mutate a NumberFormat.

Comment: It is not true, at least in JDK 8. I have just tried on the Scala REPL and added details to my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728989/retrieving-a-new-numberformat-instance-from-locale?noredirect=1#comment82418834_47728989

Comment: And? How does that prove anything? You've only shown that their toString() method returns the same string. Not that they are the same object.

Comment: The default toString defined on java.lang.Object is className@memoryLocation isn't it?

Comment: No. Not at all. Read the javadoc of Object.toString(). And of Object.hashCode().

Comment: You are right, they are equal but not the same instance. Still not clear to me how we could get into threading issue with a new instance every time :(

Comment: You can't. You get into threading issues precisely if you *don't* get a new instance every time you need a NumberFormat, and instead share the same instance between two threads.

Answer (score 3):

From the [`NumberFormat` page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

**Synchronization**

> Number formats are generally not synchronized. It is recommended to
>   create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads
>   access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

This indirectly states that the method creates a new instance with every call. Because, since NumberFormat is not thread safe, it would be unusable otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Naming I prefer

- `newXxxx` or `createXxxx` create a new instance every time.
- `getXxxx` gives you an instance if it already exists but won't create one.
- `acquireXxxx` or `valueOf` create one as needed, may or may not be new.

In this case it is like `Calendar.getInstance()` which creates a new instance each time.

Answer (score 0):

> Example:-
>
> ```
>     ClassA a = new ClassA(NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN));
> ```
>
> Normal Use of NumberFormat :
>
> ```
>     NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);    
>                        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
>                        nf.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
>                        nf.setGroupingUsed(true);
>
>
>                   
>                   java.lang.Number    num = nf.parse(Preis);
> ```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a quote from some documentation and I formatted appropriately. If I'm mistaken, the blockquote should be removed.